# Stuck on how to write a query for data transformation

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with hierarchies in different rows which has data as follows:

| StaffRefID | Name | DesignationRefID | Designation | ReportingToRefID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3497 | Garrett R. Jacobson | 1033 | Officer | 3012 |
| 3012 | Ralph J. Thoma | 1048 | Manager | 2371 |
| 2371 | SDURGA RAO | 1034 | Senior manager | 2269 |
| 2269 | Patsy G. Pedrosa | 1050 | Chief Manager | 2344 |
| 2344 | Veronica J. Martin | 1035 | Assistant General Manager | 2211 |
| 2211 | Kelly P. Fitting | 1039 | General Manager | 2301 |
| 3492 | Willie M. Tucker | 1033 | Officer | 3373 |
| 3373 | Ruth E. Murray | 1048 | Manager | 4265 |
| 4265 | Benjamin B. Polk | 1034 | Senior manager | 2344 |

Hierarchy goes like Officer --> Manager --> Senior manager --> Chief Manager --> Assistant General Manager --> General Manager.

But this is not always true. As you can see in the last row, Senior Manager directly reports to Assistant General Manager.

I want to convert these into columns, from lowest to higher. So my output would look like this.

| Officer_ID | Officer_Name | Manager_ID | Manager_Name | Senior_Manager_ID | Senior_Manager_Name | Chief_Manager_ID | Cheif_Manager_Name | Assistant_General_Manager_ID | Assistant_General_Manager_Name | General_Manager_ID | General_Manager_Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3497 | Garrett R. Jacobson | 3012 | Ralph J. Thoma | 2371 | SDURGA RAO | 2269 | Patsy G. Pedrosa | 2344 | Veronica J. Martin | 2211 | Kelly P. Fitting |
| 3492 | Willie M. Tucker | 3373 | Ruth E. Murray | 4265 | Benjamin B. Polk |  |  | 2344 | Veronica J. Martin | 2211 | Kelly P. Fitting |

What I have attempted:

```
SELECT
  a.StaffRefID as Officer_ID,
  a.Name as Officer_Name,
  b.StaffRefID as Manager_ID,
  b.Name as Manager_Name,
  c.StaffRefID as Senior_Manager_ID,
  c.Name as Senior_Manager_Name,
  d.StaffRefID as Chief_Manager_ID,
  d.Name as Cheif_Manager_Name,
  e.StaffRefID as Assistant_General_Manager_ID,
  e.Name as Assistant_General_Manager_Name,
  f.StaffRefID as General_Manager_ID,
  f.Name as General_Manager_Name
FROM
(
  SELECT
    StaffRefID,
    Name,
    DesignationRefID,
    Designation,
    ReportingToRefID
  FROM
    `dummy_project.dummy_database.hierarchy_dummy`
  WHERE
    DesignationRefID = '1033'
) as a
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT
    StaffRefID,
    Name,
    DesignationRefID,
    Designation,
    ReportingToRefID
  FROM
    `dummy_project.dummy_database.hierarchy_dummy`
) as b
ON
  a.ReportingToRefID = b.StaffRefID
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT
    StaffRefID,
    Name,
    DesignationRefID,
    Designation,
    ReportingToRefID
  FROM
    `dummy_project.dummy_database.hierarchy_dummy`
) as c
ON
  b.ReportingToRefID = c.StaffRefID
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT
    StaffRefID,
    Name,
    DesignationRefID,
    Designation,
    ReportingToRefID
  FROM
    `dummy_project.dummy_database.hierarchy_dummy`
) as d
ON
  c.ReportingToRefID = d.StaffRefID
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT
    StaffRefID,
    Name,
    DesignationRefID,
    Designation,
    ReportingToRefID
  FROM
    `dummy_project.dummy_database.hierarchy_dummy`
) as e
ON
  d.ReportingToRefID = e.StaffRefID
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT
    StaffRefID,
    Name,
    DesignationRefID,
    Designation,
    ReportingToRefID
  FROM
    `dummy_project.dummy_database.hierarchy_dummy`
) as f
ON
  e.ReportingToRefID = f.StaffRefID
```

Output I'm getting:

| Officer_ID | Officer_Name | Manager_ID | Manager_Name | Senior_Manager_ID | Senior_Manager_Name | Chief_Manager_ID | Cheif_Manager_Name | Assistant_General_Manager_ID | Assistant_General_Manager_Name | General_Manager_ID | General_Manager_Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3497 | Garrett R. Jacobson | 3012 | Ralph J. Thoma | 2371 | SDURGA RAO | 2269 | Patsy G. Pedrosa | 2344 | Veronica J. Martin | 2211 | Kelly P. Fitting |
| 3492 | Willie M. Tucker | 3373 | Ruth E. Murray | 4265 | Benjamin B. Polk | 2344 | Veronica J. Martin | 2211 | Kelly P. Fitting |  |  |

How can I accommodate for cases which don't always follow the usual hierarchy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
with temp as (
  select r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6
  from `dummy_project.dummy_database.hierarchy_dummy` r1 
  left join `dummy_project.dummy_database.hierarchy_dummy` r2 on r2.StaffRefID = r1.ReportingToRefID
  left join `dummy_project.dummy_database.hierarchy_dummy` r3 on r3.StaffRefID = r2.ReportingToRefID
  left join `dummy_project.dummy_database.hierarchy_dummy` r4 on r4.StaffRefID = r3.ReportingToRefID
  left join `dummy_project.dummy_database.hierarchy_dummy` r5 on r5.StaffRefID = r4.ReportingToRefID
  left join `dummy_project.dummy_database.hierarchy_dummy` r6 on r6.StaffRefID = r5.ReportingToRefID
  where r1.Designation = 'Officer'
)
select *  from (
  select r1.StaffRefID ID_Officer, r1.Name Name_Officer, r2.StaffRefID id, replace(r2.Designation, ' ', '_') Designation, r2.Name from temp union all
  select r1.StaffRefID, r1.Name, r3.StaffRefID, replace(r3.Designation, ' ', '_') Designation, r3.Name from temp union all
  select r1.StaffRefID, r1.Name, r4.StaffRefID, replace(r4.Designation, ' ', '_') Designation, r4.Name from temp union all
  select r1.StaffRefID, r1.Name, r5.StaffRefID, replace(r5.Designation, ' ', '_') Designation, r5.Name from temp union all
  select r1.StaffRefID, r1.Name, r6.StaffRefID, replace(r6.Designation, ' ', '_') Designation, r6.Name from temp 
)
pivot (min(id) ID, min(Name) Name for Designation in ('Manager', 'Senior_manager', 'Chief_Manager', 'Assistant_General_Manager', 'General_Manager'))
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]